# change datetime Format in angular 8 and angular mterial

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this dateTime Format :

```
Mon Feb 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)
```

iwant o change that to this format : `2020/02/03T12:35:10`

i using the `DatePipe` but it not work and not change the format :

```
this.datePipe.transform($event.value._d,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

it show me this : `YYYY/02/DD`

**how can i solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in Capital words "YYYY" and "DD", 
the correct code is :

```
this.datePipe.transform($event.value._d,'yyyy/MM/dd')
```